# How to fix this error : "../node_modules/react-native/scripts/third-party/glog-0.3.5/test-driver'. Couldn't follow symbolic link

Tags: android, react-native, glog

I've faced this error while generating signed apk from android studio.

```
 Could not list contents of '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/third-party/glog-0.3.5/test-driver'. Couldn't follow symbolic link.
```

I tried :

> 1. unlinking test-driver -> No such file found
> 2. removing glog-0.3.5 folder
> 3. removing .bin folder in node_modules

but still i can't generate apk because of the above error.

Comment: didi you find a solution ? I am having same issue with 0.3.4

Answer (score 0):

run 'rm -rf node_modules/react-native/scripts/third-party/glog-0.3.5/' and the problem is resolved

Comment: Try to elaborate more on the issue, that is just removing the folder. Anyone who runs that and doesn't know what it does by considering "problem is resolved" is going to have a hard time

Answer (score 0):

I believe this page has solutions.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14464

Thanks to @itinance and @tapz for the solutions.

Just for your ease, here is what I did.

Step 1)

```
unlink node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.4/test-driver
```

Step 2) 
Manually located third-party/glog-0.3.4 in the project root folder, deleted the “blog-0.3.4” folder.

Step 3) 
cd back to android folder and

```
./gradlew assembleRelease
```

This time, the release build was successfully compiled.